# Window oppened after double click on progress bar is immidiatly dragged into background

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winapi, topmost

I've got a non-dialog window, which opens after the user double-clicks on a progress bar.

Each time it opens, it's briefly in the foreground, after which it is dragged into background (hidden behind the main application window, the one with the progress bar).

I want for it to remain the top window, and I don't want to make it Topmost.

How do I do this?

I'm writing this in WPF 4 and c#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the window's [`Owner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner.aspx) to be the main window.